# cheked eror on dart code that i used stdin and random

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method '<'.
Receiver: "5"
Tried calling: <(44)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      guessWithPC.run (file:///C:/Users/LOGO%20CS/IdeaProjects/oop%205/bin/oop_5.dart:20:18)
#2      main (file:///C:/Users/LOGO%20CS/IdeaProjects/oop%205/bin/oop_5.dart:43:9)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)

Process finished with exit code 255

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
class guessWithPC{
  var userGuess;
  var computerGuess;
  var number;
  guessWithPC(){
    Random random;
    random =Random();
    number = random.nextInt(50);
    print('guess the number');

  }
run(){
    Random random;
    random =Random();
  userGuess = stdin.readLineSync();
  int.parse(userGuess);
  computerGuess = random.nextInt(50);
    if(userGuess < number ) {
      print('less then true');
    }
      print(computerGuess);
      if(computerGuess < number ){
        print(' computer guessed less then true');
      }
    if(userGuess > number){
      print('higher then true');
      print(computerGuess);}
      if(computerGuess > number ) {
        print(' computer guessed higher then true');
      }
        if(userGuess == number){
        print('you won');
        }
      if(computerGuess == number){
        print('computer won');
          }
  }
}
main(){
  guessWithPC guess = guessWithPC();
  guess.run();
}
```

Comment: int.parse(userGuess) is converting the string to int put not saving the value anywhere, and userGuess Still a a string and not affected.. 'var userGuessNum = int.parse(userGuess);'

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the value of int.parse inside the variable `userGuess`

```
 userGuess = stdin.readLineSync();
 userGuess=int.parse(userGuess);
```